# Getting count but ignoring duplicate column values in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Hello and today I am trying to create something with PHP using PDO for MySQL. I am hoping to create a system where it will tell me how many people have logged into my website today. I have managed to actually do what I am asking but their is 1 little extra feature I want to implement into the code to make it even better than before.

Code:

```
<?php //Gets how many users have logged in today
$res = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_logins` WHERE `Login_Timestamp` > CURRENT_DATE");
echo $res->fetchColumn();
?>
```

Here is the structure of my table in the database

Table Name: `user_logins`

Columns:

```
Id (example: 1)

Login_Username (example: John)

Login_Timestamp (example: 2015-09-13 17:13:38)

Login_Ip (example: 127.0.0.1)
```

I want to still load the count of today's values to get how many logged in today, but I only want to count an IP only once, currently I have five values that are all the same IP that has been me all day, but I only want to mark me as 1, not how many times I log in, just only once per ip. If I don't do this there is a chance it could reach a lot... is there a way to do this?

Comment: IP does not equal user, use the login name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Login_Ip) 
FROM   `user_logins` 
WHERE  `Login_Timestamp` > CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html):

```
$res = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Login_Ip) FROM `user_logins` WHERE `Login_Timestamp` > CURRENT_DATE);
```